# Using Django bulk_create objects in foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, model, save

I was reading up on Django bulk_create and a few of its "flaws":

```
"
This has a number of caveats though:

1. The model's save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent.
2. It does not work with child models in a multi-table inheritance scenario.
3. If the model's primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does.
"
```

I didn't fully understand it. So if I have a list of objects, pass it into bulk_create:

```
objList = [a, b, c,] #none are saved
model.objects.bulk_create(objList)
```

Could I still use these objects in foreign keys fine?

```
for obj in objList:
    o = otherModel(something='asdfasdf', fkey=obj)
    o.save() # will this be fine given the caveats stated above?
```

So will the foreignKey relation be okay? Also when it says 2. It does not work with child models in a multi-table inheritance scenario, it means that any model that inherits from another model(abstract or not) cannot use bulk_create?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the ids manually.  To prevent race conditions, make sure to wrap the function as a single transaction.

```
from django.db import transaction, models

@transaction.commit_on_success
def bulk_create_with_manual_ids(foo_list):
    id_start = (Foo.objects.all().aggregate(models.Max('id'))['id__max'] or 0) + 1
    for i,foo in enumerate(foo_list): foo.id = id_start + i
    return Foo.objects.bulk_create(foo_list)

objList = [Foo(),Foo(),Foo()]
foo_objects = bulk_create_with_manual_ids(objList)
Bar(foo=foo_objects[0]).save()
```

Note that this approach is unsuitable for any table that has a `serial` field or other auto-incrementing in-database generated key. The key will not be incremented by the bulk create since IDs are being generated on the Django side.

Comment: Is a single transaction enough to avoid any race condition? Is it totally safe?

Comment: I've upvoted but I should have downvoted! The id field does not autoincrement in database. This is a huge problem.

Comment: Transaction does not guarantee that nobody inserts something before you. It just guarantees that there will be no changes in the database if transaction fails.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, no you won't be able to do that, because `obj` won't have its primary key set so couldn't be used as a foreign key.

The second question, no that's not what it says at all. It specifically mentions "multi-table inheritance": inheriting from an abstract model is not multi-table inheritance.

Comment: So how would I handle the foreign key relations? Would I have to query the database to select the objects I've just inserted?

Comment: You should probably avoid `bulk_create` altogether in your case. Just create the objects individually.

Comment: Then how do you recommend handling the performance issues with doing individual saves?