# foreign key relations in django bulk_create query?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Is it possible to use bulk_create method on columns with foreign key relations??

```
class Reports(models.Model):
    groupname=models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True);
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True);


class Reportsquery(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Reports,null=True, blank=True);
    queryset=models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True);

list=[Reportsquery({"group__id":6,"queryset":"abc"}),....,...]

Reportsquery.objects.bulk_create(list)
```

similar query works on get_or_create() method but returns an error when used with 
bulk_create()
eg:

```
Reportsquery.objects.get_or_create(group__id=6,quseryset="abc")
```

The above example inserts group__id=6 into Reportsquery table

Comment: What error does `bulk_create()` return?

Comment: group__id cannot be resolved into field..

Comment: Try with one underscore, ie: `group_id`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Django bulk\_create objects in foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798767/using-django-bulk-create-objects-in-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is create instances of `Reports` alongside the `Reportsquery`, then no `bulk_create()` won't do this. However, if the instances of `Reports` already exist in the database then you could manually add their `pk`'s to the list you pass to `bulk_create()`. Then the `Reportquery` instances will be created with the correct relations to `Reports`.

Comment: No,I was just trying to map Reports instances that existed.Anyway '_' worked Thanx..

Comment: If OP was trying to create instances of Reports alongside the Reportsquery, is the another way to do it since bulk_create() won't?